# Как получить union всех ключей enum

Tags: typescript, enum, union

Есть условный enum

```
export const enum Commands {
    START = '/start',
    HELP = '/help',
    STOP = '/stop',
}
```

Нужно получить тип похожий на

```
type AcceptableCommand = '/start' | '/help' | '/stop'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type AcceptableCommand = Commands[keyof Commands];
```